# How to maintainscroll position insideUpdate panel Asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, scroll, updatepanel

i am using an asp popup control extender with panel inside update panel but panel scroll position do not maintain on click.

My aspx code for popup is,

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="TextBox1_PopupControlExtender" runat="server" DynamicServicePath=""
                  Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" TargetControlID="TextBox1" PopupControlID="Panel1" OffsetY="22">
             </asp:PopupControlExtender>
             <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="116px" Width="145px" BorderStyle="Solid"
                   BorderWidth="2px" Direction="LeftToRight" ScrollBars="Auto" BackColor="#CCCCCC"
                   Style="display: none" >
                   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataTextField="holiday_name"
                         DataValueField="holiday_name" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                   </asp:CheckBoxList>
             </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

i have used this [link](http://basgun.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/maintain-scroll-position-updatepanel-postback/) for maintaining its position that is,

may be this is the reason i have this update panel on content page and I implement java script mentioned in above link in master page

Need your suggestions

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` to Page directory of popup page.
Below is the example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestApp.Default"  ClientIDMode="AutoID" %>
```

Even you can set MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" to page directory.Apply both solution one by one.Hope this helps!